# My app Crashes in Testflight on iOS 13+ Only

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, testflight

I recently submitted an app to Tesflight for test, the app work fine for iOS 12 but consistently crashes at the same place for iOS 13.6.1 .

The app is in Testflight and is compiled with Xcode 11.5

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

this is crash log can anyone make a suggestion on what's going wrong ?

```
Incident Identifier: A516654B-34B8-411D-B6D5-12BEC3B9D2CE
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3
Process:             ********* [3921]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/******
Identifier:          com.*****
Version:             3 (1.0.1)
AppStoreTools:       11E801a
AppVariant:          1:iPhone9,3:13
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.******* [1594]


Date/Time:           2020-08-29 20:30:02.3612 +0200
Launch Time:         2020-08-29 20:29:50.4227 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.6.1 (17G80)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    4.03.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  2

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x199c79654 __exceptionPreprocess + 224 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19999bbcc objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x199b7c6ec +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 96 (NSException.m:146)
3   Foundation                      0x199fc216c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 128 (NSException.m:231)
4   FrontBoardServices              0x19ee48e84 -[FBSSerialQueue assertOnQueue] + 228 (FBSSerialQueue.m:98)
5   FrontBoardServices              0x19edfed88 -[FBSSceneImpl updateClientSettings:withTransitionContext:] + 76 (FBSSceneImpl.m:190)
6   FrontBoardServices              0x19edfefe8 -[FBSSceneImpl updateClientSettingsWithTransitionBlock:] + 152 (FBSSceneImpl.m:213)
7   FrontBoardServices              0x19edfeef8 -[FBSSceneImpl updateClientSettingsWithBlock:] + 112 (FBSSceneImpl.m:203)
8   UIKitCore                       0x19d8a46c0 -[FBSScene(UIApp) updateUIClientSettingsWithBlock:] + 168 (FBSScene+UIApp.m:41)
9   UIKitCore                       0x19dd3c448 -[UIApplication setProximityEventsEnabled:] + 108 (UIApplication.m:9203)
10  UIKitCore                       0x19d99cd50 -[UIDevice setProximityMonitoringEnabled:] + 112 (UIDevice.m:890)
11  ***                 0x100276cec -[ProximityHelper startProximitySensor] + 100 (ProximityHelper.m:53)
12 ***                  0x10025347c -[RecordSound performRecord:] + 656 (RecordSound.m:172)
13 ***                  0x10009c180 -[SoundRecordManager startCalibrationRecord:] + 200 (SoundRecordManager.m:65)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x199c7f8c0 __invoking___ + 144
15  CoreFoundation                  0x199b50a70 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 300 (NSForwarding.m:3312)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x199b51648 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 76 (NSForwarding.m:3418)
17  ****                    0x10015bef0 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 460 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
18  ****                    0x10015dfdc facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) + 244 (RCTNativeModule.mm:114)
19  ****                    0x10015dd40 operator() + 44 (RCTNativeModule.mm:75)
20  ****                    0x10015dd40 invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 88 (RCTNativeModule.mm:67)
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x19993e9a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1408)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x19993f524 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:495)
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x1998eb8a4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608 (inline_internal.h:2484)
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x1998ec294 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 416 (queue.c:3863)
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x1998f578c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588 (queue.c:6445)
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x199990b74 _pthread_wqthread + 272 (pthread.c:2351)
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x199993740 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000199a6ed88 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001999871e8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 136 (pthread.c:1458)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001998da934 abort + 100 (abort.c:110)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000199a42cc0 abort_message + 128 (abort_message.cpp:76)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000199a34e10 demangling_terminate_handler() + 296 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:65)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019999be80 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000199a4214c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000199a420e4 std::terminate() + 44 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019993f538 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 (object.m:498)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001998eb8a4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608 (inline_internal.h:2484)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001998ec294 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 416 (queue.c:3863)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001998f578c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588 (queue.c:6445)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199990b74 _pthread_wqthread + 272 (pthread.c:2351)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000199993740 start_wqthread + 8


Thread 2 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000199a45f29   x5: 0x000000016ff0a450   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x000000016ff0b000   x9: 0x32fb60d336d77b95  x10: 0x0000000199987160  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x00000001d55f9080  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000004
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000001803  x21: 0x000000016ff0a450  x22: 0x000000016ff0b0e0  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000281d6a800  x26: 0x00000002826015c0  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x00000002826015c0   fp: 0x000000016ff0a3b0   lr: 0x00000001999871e8
    sp: 0x000000016ff0a390   pc: 0x0000000199a6ed88 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

the code of proximity helper :

```
49 - (void) startProximitySensor {
50     if (!self.activatedByApp) return;
51     [timesChanged removeAllObjects];
52     UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
53     device.proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;
54    
55   
56     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
57      addObserver:self
58      selector:@selector(proximityChanged:)
59      name: proximityNotificationString
60      object:nil];
61 }
```

Comment: My guess is that you are performing a UI operation (accessing `UIDevice`in this case) from a completion handler that is not executing on the main queue. What is the code at and around line 65 in `SoundRecordManager.m`?

Comment: @Paulw11  This is the code: `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(startCalibrationRecord:(float)duration) {
  if ([AudioCheckerUtils isInUse]) {
    [self notifyAudioInUse];
    return;
  }
  isForCalibration = true;
  CalibrationRecord *calibRecord = [CalibrationRecord sharedInstance];
  calibRecord.delegate = self;
  calibRecord.audioInUseDelegate = self;
  calibRecord.noiseMeasurementInProgressDelegate = self;
  [calibRecord startRecording:duration];
}`

Comment: [edit] your question to include code. What is line 53 of proximity helper?

Answer (score 0):

In this app version, I don't need proximity helper so I deleted his call from the library and it worked on iOS 13+